# How to avoid importing again and again a module library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio, I have a library module, called `MyLib`. ***I would like to use it as a dependency to build other apps (or modules)***.

So, I imported `MyLib` into another project, made the needed changes in gradles files and everything went fine. I can import classes or Activities from `MyLib`.

Now, I would like to work on `MyLib` and the next time I try to build a project depending on it, it should (automatically) use the updated version of it.

After some search, It doesn't seem to be straightforward to do. I'm not very familiar with gradle and Maven, but I guess there must be some way to do that right ?

Has anyone some advice to share on this topic ?

Comment: Is your library uploaded in Maven Central/JCenter/A custom Nexus ?

Comment: No. It's a local library in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Is MyLib a library module of a multi-modules project or do you import the generate jar/aar of MyLib in your project ?

Comment: Post your project structure and relative `build.gradle` files.

Comment: If this lib is a local module, it is always updated

Comment: Is your question about how to get your other Android Apps to point to this library module?  If so, you can customize the the location of the module in the settings.gradle and have all of them point to it. Perhaps you could do something with symlinks here if you don't want to customize the settings.gradle file.

Comment: The MyLib module is in its own project. And I would like other projects to always use the updated version of module MyLib.